# React image path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I have folder structure like:

[image: images here]

I have 2 code:

1. components > cards.js

`<img src="path here" />`

2. App.css

`background-image: url("./images/img-1.jpg");`

questions.
Why the example 1 can access the public folder while 2 can't?

Comment: need more info about your question, it is not well explained. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the path `url("./images/img-1.jpg")` is a relative file, not a url. Change it to `url("/images/img-1.jpg")` or `url("<base_href>/images/img-1.jpg")` if you're behind a reverse proxy.

Comment: Hi, I just try your answer; but the error still the same. ```Error: Can't resolve '/images/img-2.jpg'```

Comment: As a runtime console error or a build error?

Comment: I just noticed you have two image folders. Is `img-1.jpg` in `src/images/` or `public/images/`?

Comment: My bad, just imagine the ```src/images``` doesnt exist. I dont know which error is it. Like I try to access 1 image; 1.access from js file 2.access from css file..

Comment: How do you get the error to prompt? Do you get it on `npm start` or when visiting the site you see it in console logs?